VBA filter duplicates row when only one row of the range meets the criteria
Function FilterData(x As Range, c As Variant, d As Variant) As Variant
    Dim filtered_nrows As Long
    Dim filtered_Data() As Variant
    Dim Numrows As Long
    Dim Rows As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Determine the number of rows that meet the criteria
    filtered_nrows = numbrows(x, c, d)

    ' If no rows meet the criteria, return an empty array
    If filtered_nrows = 0 Then
        FilterData = Array()
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Resize the array to hold the filtered data
    ReDim filtered_Data(1 To filtered_nrows, 1 To 4)

    ' Get the total number of rows in the range
    Numrows = x.Rows.count
    Rows = 1

    ' Loop through each row in the range
    For i = 1 To Numrows
        ' Check if the current row meets the criteria
        If LCase(x.Cells(i, 1).Value) = LCase(c) And x.Cells(i, 2).Value = d Then
            ' Populate the filtered data array with specific columns
            filtered_Data(Rows, 1) = x.Cells(i, 6).Value
            filtered_Data(Rows, 2) = x.Cells(i, 4).Value
            filtered_Data(Rows, 3) = x.Cells(i, 13).Value
            filtered_Data(Rows, 4) = x.Cells(i, 9).Value
            Rows = Rows + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Return the filtered data array
    FilterData = filtered_Data
End Function

Function numbrows(tableRange As Range, criteria As Variant, criteria2 As Variant) As Long
    Dim filteredRows As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    filteredRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tableRange, 0, 1), criteria, _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tableRange, 0, 2), criteria2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    numbrows = filteredRows
End Function

Trying to filter out data in a range and output specific columns from the row.
Tried changing to a dynamic resizing code but that provides a value error.
Seems it only does not work when the criteria run is met for only one row like the images here.
.
.
For ease of use the formula is meant to work even if the range input is beyond the dimension of my defined array. Thus, it should be N/A values beyond that one row for this case.

It looks like this is a "feature" ,  i.e. a single row 2-D array is treated as a 1-D array. Fix is to ensure the destination range is sized to match the array using Resize(Ubound(ar,1),Ubound(ar,2))

Thanks for the reply, I can't seem to resize unless I run a sub, though I would prefer for my function to work. Even then, resizing does not seem to fix my code, I tried to resize it but i would get an error that says im outside the subscript range

How are you writing the output of the function to the sheet ? What is the code ?

I highlighted 4 columns and until the 99th row and enter  FilterData(the range, criteria 1, criteria 2) and I will ctrl + shift + enter

Modify the numbrows function something like this, because Index returns only one
cell in your code.
Function numbrows(tableRange As Range, criteria As Variant, criteria2 As Variant) As Long
    Dim filteredRows As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    filteredRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
        tableRange.Columns(1), criteria, _
        tableRange.Columns(2), criteria2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    numbrows = filteredRows
End Function

this will count the occurences in the whole columns.
